# Publish Media item from Sitecore 8.1 Experience Editor

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have a image field in a controller rendering(ImageCtrl) and data source template for it. In Experience Editor the ImageCtrl is added and assigned to a new data source. I click on the image placeholder, the media library opens and I upload one new picture from my PC. Then I save the page and publish from Experience Editor.

The image I've upload is not published under Media library so the image is not displayed. As I know this functionality is not supported out of the box by Sitecore.

The Sitecore solution is integrated with C# MVC.

Is their a way to catch the publish from Experience Editor and publish the images? How can I do this publish so the content editor won't need to go to media library to and publish the images?

**EDIT:**
This is how sitecore  databases look after publish:

Web Image Datasource
http://prntscr.com/aa8eyn 
Web Media Library
http://prntscr.com/aa8f7h

Master Image Datasource
http://prntscr.com/aa8g31
Master Media Library 
http://prntscr.com/aa8gae

The C# view looks like this: http://prntscr.com/aa8hid

The imagefield is a subitem of the datasource of a subitem of the page.

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't publish it as well. Is there some configuration that should be implemented?

Comment: How you reference the datasource item for the controller rendering?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber yes in the datasource the image path is changed in the master database. In the web database the datasource the image field doesn't have the new image.

Comment: what is Core Image Datasource? did you put images in Core DB?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber sorry it was web and master databases not core and master.

Comment: Can you put also image with the data source of the component?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Image Datasource is the component datasource. I've found this https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1210 I don't know if this is fixed in 8.1

Answer (score 2):

I tried to add a new picture and publish in Habitat solution and is working OOTB.

You have to choose Publish Related items like on picture attached.

[image]

Comment: I've update the question can you please take another look at it?